# String useState Value Is Empty after Storing a Value in an API Response to It

Tags: reactjs, typescript

What I am trying to do here is to extract the id (Number) from an API response, parse it into String, and set it to its state variable. However, when I console log it, it gives me an empty string, which is the default value of it. If anyone could give me a suggestion or tell me what's wrong, that would be greatly appreciated. My briefly reproduced code snippet is down below:

```
  const [userId, setUserId] = useState<string>("");


  const getMyUserId = async () => {
    const { data: objects } = await axios.get("/"); 
    const user_id = objects.objects[0].id.toString(); 
    setUserId(user_id);
    console.log("userId", userId); <- output is empty string
  };

  const getMyCalendarId = async () => {
    const url = `/${userId}/cal/calendars`;
    const { data: objects } = await axios.get(`${url}`);
    const calendar_id = objects.objects[0].id.toString();
    setCalendarId(calendar_id);
  };
    
  useEffect(() => {
    getMyUserId(); <- render every time page is loaded
    getMyCalendarId
  }, []);
```

Comment: setUserId is an asynchronous process. `console.log("userId", userId)` is fired before `setUserId(user_id)` is completed. You need to wait for the completion before console.log("userId", userId)

Comment: You are right. However, `userId ` will be used for another function which calls another api call using it such as `await axios.get(`/api/${userId}`/abc`. Then, api request url becomes ike `/api/abc` (ideally I want it to be `/api/12345(userId)/abc`). Is there any way that I can call the latter function after making sure `userId` was successfully set?

Comment: **useEffect(()=>{ getMyUserId(); }, [])**;   --> userId will be changed once page is loaded, And  **useEffect(()=>{ getMyCalendarId(); }, [userId]);**  --> Once userId changed, getMyCalendarId() will be called. Component can have **multiple** useEffect();

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve the user id you should access `data`, instead of `objects`. Like this:

```
const user_id = data.objects[0].id.toString();
```

`objects` is the typing of `data`, it is not the actual property.

Comment: TS says `data` cannot be found. I even tried `const data = await axios.get('/)`, but still the `userId` is empty .As @ioedeveloper mentioned above, anther function which is using `userId` gets called before `user_id` is set to `userId`.

Comment: If you `console.log(data)`, what is your output? Do you actually get something back from the server? Also, if you want to use `userId` inside of you should `await getMyUserId()` inside of useEffect, because now it will call getMyCalendarId() before the userId is retrieved.